# Filter by 'code' using odoo product API

Tags: php, odoo, odoo-9

I'm trying to filter by a specific product code using odoo's PHP api. If I filter by `qty_available > 0` it works fine:

```
$records = $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $pass, 'product.product', 'search_read', array(
  array(
    array('qty_available', '>', 0),
  ),
), array(
  'fields' => array('code', 'display_name', 'qty_available')
));
```

... but when I filter by code, it returns all results, essentially ignoring any filters:

```
$records = $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $pass, 'product.product', 'search_read', array(
  array(
    array('code', '=', 'T-0001'),
  ),
), array(
  'fields' => array('code', 'display_name', 'qty_available')
));
```

Does anyone know why this may be happening please? It also works fine using an integer ID, just not the string code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Prakash Sharma for his help, but it turns out out that the actual way to get it to work was to use `product.product`'s field `default_code` rather than `code`, which fortunately is searchable. This may be different depending on others' setups, but I wasn't willing to go in and change the database and I think the internal reference should be kept pure as it was designed.

Answer (score 1):

In the model  `product.product`  [`code`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/product/product.py#L948) field is the [**functional field/compute field**](http://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#computed-fields)  .

> These type of  field are  **Not Searchable** by default.

But you can mark the store=True , and search it.

**NOTE:There are pros as well as con's of marking the store=True**

Comment: I see, thanks for your answer. Yesterday was my first experience with odoo so I wasn't aware of details like non-indexable fields. What are cons of `store=True`?

Comment: Also, can a field be set as searchable through the front-end or would I only be able to access it through the API?

Comment: What are cons of store=True: Once a  compute field is  marked as  store =True, it will not compute after that, for handling this you will have to use @api.depends with the compute function so that it can called on the change of depends field   .